Is it defamatory to publish nonsense under somebody else's name?
Imagine that a supposedly academic journal intentionally publishes an AI-generated article which is full of claims which are easily verifiable nonsense to any expert in the field. The article is published under the name of a real academic who works in the field, and that academic had no involvement in creating the nonsense article, and would definitely not have agreed to publish it under her own name.
If a member of the academic community in the same field were to read the article and believe that the author attribution were correct, then they would most likely form a low opinion of the supposed author's competence in that field. However, an ordinary member of the public would not have the expertise to judge that the article is nonsense, and might think that having published an article in the field is a positive indication of her expertise. The article itself doesn't contain any statements about the claimed author's expertise, the article's only claim related to her is that she is the author.
Is the journal's false attribution defamatory?

This is a hypothetical question not restricted to a particular jurisdiction, so answers about any jurisdiction are welcome. The question is inspired by a real situation posted on Academia SE, but the question should be answered based on the hypothetical facts stated here, not in that post.

Why would it matter that it's AI-generated. Human-generated nonsense would be just as bad, wouldn't it?

In the actual situation, the journal is not reputable, so it may be the case that nothing they publish is taken seriously. It would be like trying to sue The Onion.

@Barmar Why does it matter why it matters to OP? If you think it's all the same, you can just go ahead and answer the question.

@bdb484 For some reason both questions mentioned the AI-generated nature, as if it matters.

Being AI-generated might indeed change the situation. It shows disregard for the author, but it can also change mens rea from malice to negligence, if the AI picked that name at random.

@Therac I think it's going to be for courts to decide in the upcoming years to what extent "my AI generated bad thing XYZ for me" flies as an excuse. My suspicion is that whether you or an AI you controlled generated defamatory content will end up making as little difference as whether your fist or your stick hit a person. But honestly this discussion could still go either way.

@Therac Also, in the specific case I doubt a court would believe that the name was picked "at random" - the author is an internationally known professor at a business university, the article is about international business, and the author's name is fairly unique. I think it's a tough sell claiming that the name was entirely arbitrary and in no way chosen intentionally to give credit to the article.

Indeed @xLeitix, the OP for the question on Academia SE even mentioned that the combination of institution and name uniquely identified them. Whether they specifically selected that person, or prompted the AI to pick an existing academic, I would struggle to believe that it managed to produce an existing person by pure happenstance.

In jurisdictions with moral rights, it might also be a wrong of false attribution.

@Barmar It being AI-generated guarantees that any practical experiments described in the text were not actually conducted, for example. I think also generally people are familiar with the fact that AIs are good at generating plausible-sounding nonsense that may require expertise to recognise as nonsense, so this is a concise way of framing the question.

The defamatory act is the statement that the academic wrote the nonsense
It’s not true and it harms their reputation.
It’s conceptually no different from saying the academic faked their data, or didn’t earn their degrees, or is a secret Nazi.

In a specialist field, who's to judge that the statement is rubbish? Far better to focus on the false attribution.

Does it matter that it only harms their reputation in the eyes of a fellow expert? Some laws have an "ordinary person" test, but I don't know if defamation is among them in any jurisdiction.

@MarkMorganLloyd But the fact that the paper is rubbish is precisely why the attribution would harm the academic's reputation.

@KarlKnechtel Being seen as taking credit for work one hasn't done could also harm an academic's reputation. In that case, it would be the perception of their character that is harmed rather than the perception of their competence.

@kaya3: That probably makes damages harder to prove, but you can get a couple of expert witnesses to testify that yes, they would be put off by reading the plaintiff's name on this pile of rubbish, and that would at least be a start.

@kaya3: My understanding is that defamation (at least for the US) is in relation to the person's community. I would fully expect that at least one "community" for an academic would be fellow members of their particular sub-field.

Is "paper with X's name attached" the same as "statement that X wrote the paper"? There isn't literally an explicit statement to that effect in this case. At a minimum, I suspect the wording of this answer might be improved.

@KarlKnechtel Publishing any statement relating to- for example- development work being done could be enough to invalidate a patent application: whether or not it appears to be rubbish to one "skilled in the art". Or alternatively, apparently having a paper in a journal widely agreed to be predatory might be viewed as endorsing its standing: rubbish or not. Focus on the false attribution, and don't put oneself in the position of trying to prove to a non-technical court that the content is rubbish.

Yes, the journal's false attribution is likely defamatory, as it harms the academic's reputation by associating her with false information, damaging her standing among peers. It misleads the public, potentially causing further harm in future.

Most scientific/research journals specify it as their policy that the corresponding authors (i.e., the one's submitting the article) should obtain an accord of all the authors mentioned. (Conversely, all the authors mentioned should be familiar with the text and take responsibility for it.) Some go as far as to send notifications to the authors concerned (where their email addresses are available) or may even require a letter of consent.
Here is, e.g., Physical Review policy:

Corresponding author. This individual represents all listed authors during the peer-review process and must be designated for every submission. The Corresponding Author should inform all authors of the submission of a paper and the outcome of important steps in the review process.
[...]
By submitting the manuscript, the Corresponding Author certifies the following:
[...]

All listed authors contributed significantly to the concept, design, execution, interpretation, or write-up of the research study.
All those who made significant contributions were offered the opportunity to be listed as authors.
All listed authors are aware of and agree to the submission of the manuscript.


(emphasis is mine.)

This doesn't address the question, which is about whether a journal doing this intentionally would constitute defamation. We can suppose that a journal which publishes fake papers under real people's names is not actively informing those people about their practices.

How is that practically possible with these thousand plus author papers now days or do the groups have some presubmission agreements around authorship?

I'm really really curious about these supposed 1000+ author papers. That sounds like a nightmare to manage and I don't expect that anything but the most well funded most ground breaking research would ever be able to support thousands of researchers for the duration of the research project. I doubt there's many 1000+ author papers in existence. Not enough to cause regular admin issues at least as these projects would take years to complete

@TheEvilMetal 1000+ are rarity and usually come from large projects involving many labs working in the same time on different part of the project. Like sequencing for the first time human DNA or the experiments at CERN - both costly international projects. This is a bit like citing the employee list in a company report - they all deserve the credit, but many of them may not even know each other.

The Peanut butter - Earth rotation paper has quite a lot of authors, of the order of 200

@TheEvilMetal How many is many? Such papers are of course rare compared to papers with fewer authors, but back in 2019 it was reported that over 1500 such papers were published just in the period between 2009 and 2018.
